# Spacing the contents of a dropdown menu in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I've made a drop down menu with CSS and jQuery using unordered lists. The problem is in firefox the spacing of the list items is not equal. It works in Chrome and IE.I've tried using a reset.css but it didn't work also : http://jsfiddle.net/dyUwm/20/

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.0/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/quemSomos/apresentacao.xhtml">Apresentação</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/quemSomos/diretoria.xhtml">Diretoria e Conselhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/quemSomos/nossaHistoria.xhtml">Nossa História</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/quemSomos/nossosMestres.xhtml">Nossos Mestres</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/quemSomos/nossaSanga.xhtml">Nossa Sanga</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">O ZEN BUDISMO</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/oZenBudismo/pratica.xhtml">Prática</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/retiros.xhtml">Sesshins (Retiros)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/oZenBudismo/datas.xhtml">Datas Comemorativas</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/oZenBudismo/textos.xhtml">Textos e Sutras</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/oZenBudismo/sugestoes.xhtml">Sugestão de Leituras</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a href="#">COMO PARTICIPAR</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/programacaoRegular.xhtml">Programação Regular</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/retiros.xhtml">Sesshins (Retiros)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/doacoes.xhtml">Doações</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/tornarseMembro.xhtml">Tornar-se Membro</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/comoParticipar/oficinas.xhtml">Oficinas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/vilaZen.xhtml">VILA ZEN</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">GALERIA DE IMAGENS</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">MAIS</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/ViaZen/faces/mais/links.xhtml">Links</a></li>
        <!--                                <li><h:link outcome="/mais/links" value="Aconteceu"/></li>-->
        <!--                                <li><h:link outcome="/mais/relatos" value="Relatos de Experiências"/></li>-->
        <!--                                <li><h:link outcome="/mais/links" value="Zen Peacemakers"/></li>-->
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>

</div>
</html>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;    
}

#wrapper h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color:black;

}

#wrapper ul.menu {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:50px 0 30px 0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper ul.menu a {
    color: #666;
    font: bold 12px Lora, serif;
    text-decoration: none;    
}


#wrapper ul.menu li
    {    
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0;
        margin-right:20px;
        position: relative;

    }
#wrapper ul.menu li a
    {    display: block;
         text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap
}

#wrapper ul.menu li a:hover
    {    
    color:#163a24;
    }

#wrapper ul.menu li ul
        {    
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            border-radius:10px;
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #888888;
        }


#wrapper ul.menu ul li
        {    
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        text-transform:capitalize;
                           }

#wrapper ul.menu ul li a
        {    
        width: auto;
        border-bottom:1px solid #225A37;
                padding:10px;
                }

       #wrapper ul.menu ul li a:hover {
                color:#2E8052;                    
      }                    

#wrapper ul.menu ul li:last-child a                
        {
        border-bottom:none;        
        }
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){

                $("ul.menu li").hover(function(){

                    $(this).addClass("hover");
                    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

                }, function(){

                    $(this).removeClass("hover");
                    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

                });

                $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

            })
```

​
​

Comment: looks even on mine (FF ver 17+)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look messed up on My FF Browser, but usually when issues like this happens, I use normalize.css in conjunction with reset.css, Cross Browser compatability is always a challenge, but normalize tries to overwrite the browser's default stylesheet to render similarly on all browsers.